Hedging an equity portfolio
In the section on hedging an equity portfolio, hull talks about how you should divide the value of the portfolio by the value of each future to determine the optimal number of futures contracts(assuming the portfolio mirrors a well-diversified index).
Wouldn't it be more accurate to divide the number of index units in the portfolio by the number of index units in each future? In fact, the former approach only works if the index price is equal to the index futures price.

11th global edition, page 85

(OK, I found it. You and I should work carefully through the example 3.4 to see why he does it this way. It seems he is trying to match the portfolio value at expiration, not the current value.)

Ok I might have some idea why. On page 85, the formula given is:
N* = Beta x V_A/V_F = Beta x SQ_A/FQ_F
where S is the spot price and F is the futures price for the index. Here, given how beta is obtained, beta*S/F is the hedge ratio. In theory, this ratio should change on a daily basis as spot price and future price adjust but on page 83, he mentions that these adjustments are generally ignored.
Let me know if this makes sense.

OK, it makes sense

@secretrevaler Can you pls revise your question, if you still have one, to include your later comments?
